# Python multiprocessing calculations significantly slower than sequential calculations

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i was playing with multiprocessing in python. I'm trying do distribute calculations on arrays to multiple CPU cores. In order to do that I'm forking as many processes as `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` returns and I'm passing subsets of the array to the processes (by partitioning the array indices). The array is operated on as a shared memory object.
However, for varying array sizes I cannot experience any runtime improvements. Why is that?
This is just a toy example, I'm not trying to achieve something with this calculations.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time
import sharedmem


def some_function_mult(q, arr, index, width):
q.put((sum(arr[index:index+width])/np.amax(arr[index:index+width])**2)/40)

def some_function(arr, index, width):
return sum((arr[index:index+width])/np.amax(arr[index:index+width])**2)/40

def main(): 
num = mp.cpu_count()
n = 200000000
width  = n/num
random_array = np.random.randint(0,255,n)                                                                                                                                                                        
shared = sharedmem.empty(n)
shared[:] = random_array
print (shared)


queue = mp.Queue()

processes = [mp.Process(target=some_function_mult, args=(queue, shared, i*width, width)) for i in xrange(num)]

start_time = time.time()
for p in processes:
    p.start()

result = []
for p in processes:
    result.append(queue.get())

for p in processes:
    p.join()
end_time = time.time()

print ('Multiprocessing execution time = ' + str(end_time-start_time))
print (result)

result = []
start_time  =time.time()

for i in range(num):
    result.append(some_function(random_array, i*width, width))
end_time = time.time()

print ('Sequential processing time = '  + str(end_time-start_time))
print (result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: How many cores are you working with? I don't think you are actually working on a shared memory array, instead, multiprocessing is *pickling and copying* your `sharedmem` object, and sending it to separate processes. Of course, I only browsed the docs for `sharedmem`, but I think it is meant to work with the built-in methods, i.e. `mapReduce`, not with multiprocessing.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: IOW, I think it isn't surprising that copying your `sharedmem` array `num` times, which involve pickling and unpickling, and then the overhead of starting `num` interpreters etc, and then aggregating the results, will ever be faster than simply doing those operations on your array sequentially.

Comment: @juanapa.arrivillaga: I'm working with 4 cores. I changed the shared memory object to 'multiprocessing.Array' and initialized it with 'random_array'. Still there is no runtime improvement.  So is there are solution that does not produce that much overhead? I thought that if i create a shared memory array, those forked processes would just access this array via pointer to the memory location, thus no need for copying. Why does this seem to be so hard to realize in Python? And wouldn't it be that starting 4 additional interpreters soon be compensated if the array is large enough